# Nonzero solutions of an infinite product

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, inequalities, products

Let $-\frac{1}{2}\le a \le\frac{1}{2}$ and $b\in[0,\infty)$.

Definitions:  $$f_k(a;b):=\frac{(2k+\frac{1}{2}+a)^2+b}{(2k+\frac{1}{2}-a)^2+b}(\frac{k}{k+1})^{2a},$$
$$f(a;b):=\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty f_k(a;b)$$
QUESTIONs:

(1) Does $f(a;b)=1$ have any solution with $a\neq 0$?

(2) If yes: Single points $(a;b)$ or areas ?

Thank you very much !

EDIT: Have changed $(\frac{k}{k+1})^a$ to $(\frac{k}{k+1})^{2a}$. It was a mistake.

2th EDIT: It seems to be $f(a,b)<\pi^{2a}$ for $a>0$, at least for e.g. $b>2$. Correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us show that for each $a\in[-\frac12,\frac12]\setminus\{0\}$ there is a unique $b\in(0,\infty)$ such that $f(a;b)=0$. 
By factoring $(2k+\frac{1}{2}\pm a)^2+b$ 
as $4 [k + \frac14\, (1 \pm 2 a - 2 i\sqrt b)][k + \frac14\, (1 \pm 2 a + 2 i\sqrt b)]$, 
noting that $\prod_{k=1}^n(k+c)=\Gamma(n+1+c)/\Gamma(1+c)$ for complex $c$, 
and then using the Stirling formula (see e.g. formula (1) in **[[Kilbas--Saigo](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1363-4.pdf)]**), we have this closed-form expression for $f(a;b)$:
\begin{equation}
 f(a;b)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac54-\frac a2+\frac{i\sqrt b}2)\Gamma(\frac54-\frac a2-\frac{i\sqrt b}2)}
 {\Gamma(\frac54+\frac a2+\frac{i\sqrt b}2)\Gamma(\frac54+\frac a2-\frac{i\sqrt b}2)}
= \bigg(\frac{\big|\Gamma(\frac54-\frac a2+\frac{i\sqrt b}2)\big|}
 {\big|\Gamma(\frac54+\frac a2+\frac{i\sqrt b}2)\big|}\bigg)^2 . \tag{1}
\end{equation}
By formula $(1)$, 
\begin{equation}
 f(a;0)=\Big(\frac{g(a)}{g(-a)}\Big)^2, 
\end{equation}
where $g(a):=\Gamma(\frac54-\frac a2)$ is convex in $a$. Since $g'(-\frac4{10})>0$, it follows that $g$ is increasing on $[-\frac4{10},\frac12]$, and so, $f(a;0)>1$ for $a\in[0,\frac4{10}]$. Also, for $a\in(\frac4{10},\frac12]$ one has $g(a)>g(\frac4{10})>g(-\frac12)\vee g(-\frac4{10})\ge g(-a)$, and so, $f(a;0)>1$ for $a\in(\frac4{10},\frac12]$ as well. Thus, $f(a;0)>1$ for all $a\in(0,\frac12]$, which is equivalent to $f(a;0)<1$ for all $a\in[-\frac12,0)$.

Next, using again formula $(1)$ above and formula (3) in **[[Kilbas--Saigo](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1363-4.pdf)]**, it is not hard to see that that $f(a;\infty-)=0<1$ for all $a\in(0,\frac12]$ and $f(a;\infty-)=\infty>1$ for all $a\in[-\frac12,0)$.

Also, $f(a;b)$ is (strictly) increasing in $b\ge0$ for $a\in[-1/2,0)$ and decreasing in $b\ge0$ for $a\in(0,1/2]$ -- because $f_k(a;b)$ has these properties, for each $k$.

It follows that indeed for each $a\in[-\frac12,\frac12]\setminus\{0\}$ there is a unique $b\in(0,\infty)$ such that $f(a;b)=1$.

---

For an illustration of the above result, here are graphs of $f(a,b)$ and $\text{sgn}(f(a,b)-1)$, suggesting something like a straight line of roots at $b\approx1.6$.

[image]

The "straight" line is not quite straight, as the following regional plots of $f(a,b)>1$ suggest:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your usefull answer. But the interpretation is difficult for me: Does it mean, that e.g. for $b>10>>1.6$ is $f(a;b)\ne 1$?

Comment: Is it possible to see: (1) if there is a supremum for $f(a,b)$ ? (2) if there exists a value $b_0$ ($a<\frac{1}{2}$ OR $a>\frac{1}{2}$) that $f(a,b)<1$ for all $b>b_0$ ? (I know, it's difficult to answer - that's the reason for my questions) AND: Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe also needs a note on why $f(a,b)$ continuous in $(a,b)$.  Some sort of uniform convergence, I guess.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: That's right! Your answer was very useful.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : $f(a,b)$ is continuous because of formula $(1)$ and the continuity of the (meromorphic) Gamma function everywhere on $\mathbb C$ except at its poles at the non-positive integers.

Comment: Finally, a complete answer.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis:Thanks a lot for your patience and useful considerations ! I don't understand all at the moment but I will see. (One note: I think you mean  $f(a;b)=1$ and not $f(a;b)=0$ at the end of your explanations.)

Comment: @user90369 : Thank you for letting me know about the typo at the end (the same one was at the beginning, by copy-and-pasting). They are now fixed.

Comment: I have added a couple of details on the derivation of the closed-form Gamma-values expression for $f(a;b)$.

Comment: Thank you. And: I think that the script of Kilbas-Saigo is helpfull !

Comment: In $(1)$, I have added a simpler expression for $f(a;b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Numerically, I get this ($500$ factors)...
red is ${}> 1$, yellow is ${} < 1$.

[image: graph]

the jagged parts are probably just from numerical approximation.  I'm guessing $f=1$ is only curves, and always $b < 1.8$.

The Gamma function formula yields a similar picture.

Here is the interesting location:

[image: zoom]

Comment: Yes, this looks similar to the regional plot for the exact expression in terms of the Gamma values. Thank you for confirming that.

Comment: Thanks for your informations !  At the moment I can not see the graph because of my limited opportunities but I will check later.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: Thank you very much for these interesting graphs. With the graphs one can very well understand the behavior of the product .

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any $a\in[-\frac12,\frac12]\setminus\{0\}$ and $b\in[0,\infty)$ one has $f_k(a;b)-1\sim a/k$ as $k\to\infty$. So, the product diverges to $0$ if $a<0$ and to $\infty$ if $a>0$. Thus, the equation $f(a;b)=1$ has no solutions with $a\neq 0$.

---

Details on $f_k(a;b)-1\sim a/k$ as $k\to\infty$: 
\begin{equation}
 f_k(a;b)=\Big(1+\frac{2a(4k+1)}{(2k+\frac12-a)^2+b}\Big)
 \Big(1-\frac1{k+1}\Big)^a
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  =\Big(1+\frac{(2+o(1))a}k\Big)\Big(1-\frac{(1+o(1))a}k\Big)=1+\frac{(1+o(1))a}k. 
\end{equation}

Comment: I checked it in two different ways, and I get $a/k$, rather than $O(1/k^2)$.

Comment: I got $a/k$ also.  Maybe the definition has a typo, in which case the OP should clarify.

Comment: I have added details on $a/k$.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct.

Comment: I am very sorry, I have made a mistake. It must be $2a$ instead of $a$. Thanks for the good help!!!